# 'Guess 2/3 of the average' normal form

Tags: game-theory

I wanted to represent the 'Guess 2/3 of the average' problem in normal form. The rules for this game are below:

> - There are two players.  Each player names an integer between 1 and 100.
> - The player who names the integer closest to two thirds of the
>     average integer gets a reward of 2, the other players get nothing.
> - If there is a tie, each player gets reward of 1

Would the normal form simply be this?

[image]

Comment: Not counting ties I think that the player naming the smaller number wins. In other words it's a rewriting of a much simpler game. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The rows and columns correspond to strategies, not to results like "correct" or "incorrect". The normal form of this game has $100$ rows and $100$ columns, corresponding to the $100$ different strategies for each player. For instance, the entry corresponding to player $1$ naming $5$ and player $2$ naming $13$ would contain the payoffs $2$ and $0$.

Comment: Could 'guessing less than 67' and 'guessing over 67' be appropriate strategies or would I still need to have every possible outcome as rows/column

Comment: @joe: The latter. By "strategies", I meant "pure strategies". There are also mixed strategies, which randomise over the pure strategies, but the game is defined by the outcome for each pair of pure strategies.

Comment: This is what I got after the changes: http://i.imgur.com/W9QLn3o.png. Your example you give is confusing as I thought the payoff would be (2, 0) since player 1 naming 5 is closer to 2/3 of the average: 6

Comment: @joe: Sorry for the mistake in the example -- somehow I was thinking of the sum instead of the average -- I've corrected it. Your table looks right. (Of course it's just a small section of the full $100\times100$ table.) As Christian Blatter wrote, the player closer to $\frac23$ of the average is simply the player with the lower number.